# Rouché's theorem for $|z|>2$

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Can someone help me find how many roots does this polynom :
$p(z)=z^4-5z+1$ have on set $|z|>2$ using Rouché's theorem?

I'm thinking like this:
This polynomial has 4 roots(fundamental theorem of algebra) , and by applying Rouché's theorem I can find that $p$ has one root on unit disc $|z|<1$ , (since the largest coefficient is at $z$).

In similar way , I got that $p$ has 4 roots on $|z|=2$ , since by using $g(z)=z^{4}$ ,I have
$|p-g|=|-5z+1|<10+1=11<2^4=|g(z)|$ , so by Rouché's theorem $p$ has 4 roots in $|z|<2$.

Meanwhile, I have to find number of roots in $|z|>2$ , and by the proof above, I would say that $p$ has NO roots on $|z|>2$ (since it has 4 in total , and I got that all of them are in the interior of this set).

But,the result has to be 3-polynom $p$ has 3 roots on $|z|>2$. Can someone please help me with this?I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct.If $|z| >2$ then $|p(z)| \geq |z^{4}-5z| -1=|z|(|z|^{3} -5)-1>2(8-5)-1 >0$ so there is no root for $|z| >2$.

Comment: Oh,so my result is ok?Thanks a lot!It must be a mistake in the book I'm working this from.There,the result is 3,and I really didn't know how can I get that...Thanks a lot!